# fontsize in dropdown menus in ckeditor in TYPO3

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

the style dropdown menus in ck_editor in TYPO3 8.7 shows the labels in the same font size as in the editied text. E. G. when h1 is in the rte.css formatted as 30 px the text in the dropdown is 30px too and therefore the entry is not readable. Is there a possibilty to fix the font size in the dropdown menus to 12-15px, always and in every context? Without destroying the wysiwyg in the editable text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you can do that by using in your rte.css something like:

```
.cke_panel_listItem h1{
  font-size:15px;
}

h1{
  font-size:60px;
}
h2{
  font-size:40px;
}
h3{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Please note that as the dropdown is loaded inside an iframe, you might have to kill your browser's cache to see some change.

See also [CKEditor remove style preview from Styles dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435725/ckeditor-remove-style-preview-from-styles-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks!! In fact all it needs is
   .cke_panel_listItem {
      font-size:13px !important;
   }